# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos columnas o mas de otras tablas y formas otra columna en otra tabla con SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, xml

Tengo estas tablas:

tabla1

| id1 | nombre | codigo1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 1 |
| 2 | bbbb | 2 |

tabla2

| id2 | nombre | codigo2 | fkid1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | AAAA | 01 | 1 |
| 22 | BBBB | 02 | 2 |

tabla3

| id3 | nombre | codigo3 | fkid2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | ffff | 05 | 12 |
| 23 | jjjj | 06 | 22 |

Como se puede ver en el ejemplo, la tabla2 esta relacionada con tabla1 y la tabla3 con la tabla2

Lo que necesito es mostrar los códigos de cada tabla, pero concatenado sus códigos, algo así:

### Código formado

10105

20206

Empleando para este fin consultas SQL.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para que base de datos? que tiene que ver xml aca? y msqli? y cual es el problema que tuviste, no pudiste hacer los joins o concatenar o que cosa?

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(a.codigo1, b.codigo2, c.codigo3)
from tabla1 a
inner join tabla2 b on b.fkid1 = a.id
inner join tabla3 c on c.fkid2 = b.id;
```

Creo que esto te puede llegar a servir para lograr tu cometido.
Basicamente inner joineas las tablas por su fk y para obtener el resultado deseado, realizar un concat del codigo de cada una de las tablas

Comment: Por favor evita responder a preguntas donde el usuario no ha demostrado esfuerzo